# How can I enable login shell to install RVM in st terminal?

Tags: terminal, shell, login, ruby, rvm

I use [rvm](http://rvm.io/integration) for my Ruby dev work, and I'd like to switch to [st](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/St#Shell) as my terminal. I'm currently using uxterm, which is ok, but doesn't have the flexibility I'm looking for. However, I can't seem to get RVM working, which is critical. There doesn't seem to be a documented way of enabling a login shell.

How can I enable login shell in st?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can specify this as an argument:

```
$ st -e /bin/bash --login
```

I added details to the RVM documentation:

https://github.com/rvm/rvm-site/commit/003d3b092482bb4a558a3284e6f0e40a10b0c31b